# What do I call a person who submits content?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

There is a section on my site, where users can submit content.

I'm not sure how to call it.

There are three cases:

1) user can submit own content, so he could be an author

2) user can submit thirdparty content, so he is just a submitter

3) user can submit both his and third-party content.

First case - call him an author or contributor, that's ok.

Second case - submitter.

What do I call a person in the third case? In this case he could either an author or a submitter or both. Is there some middle word, that can describe both ways?

Is there some better word, similar to the meaning of submitter?

Comment: note that it is perfectly normal for someone to have multiple roles, if you're designing a website where a user can only have a single role, then you probably want to revise your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a word to indicate where on the site people can submit content, *submit here*, *submissions*, and *contribute here* all work. If you really need to define the different types of contributors, it could get confusing. Even is someone is the author of their content, they are still submitting it. *Submitter*, while technically correct, brings to mind someone who is in submission to something or someone. This site uses **user** to name participants. Perhaps the types of submissions could be categorized (color-coded?) in some way without needing to come up with different names for those generating the content.

Comment: Submitter sounds awkward.

Answer (score 13):

I think "contributor" would serve to cover all cases.  It does not necessarily imply that the contribution is original.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps a suitable word would be "contributor"?

Answer (score 0):

A user who *provides* content can also be termed a *provider*, although that can come across as too technical.  Also the verb form for something like a button is a bit awkward: "Click here to Provide" or "Provide Content Here."

Answer (score -1):

Try "*proposer*", i.e. person who puts forward a proposal or a submission.